# Check image source for variables in array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array of products that I want to be able to check via jQuery to see if any of them are present in a images source url. I've made the following but dont know the correct way to call my variable inside the script:

```
$(function() {
    /*Products we to target*/
    var products = ["product1.jpg", "product2.jpg", "product3.jpg"];
    $('ul.product-list li img[src*=products]').addClass('targeted-product');
});
```

How do I call my variable inside the `img[src*=]` selector and is the above code is going to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
    /*Products we to target*/
    var products = ["product1.jpg", "product2.jpg", "product3.jpg"];
    $.each( products, function( key, value ) {
       $('ul.product-list li img[src^="' + value + '"]').addClass('targeted-product');
    });      
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
 .targeted-product{background-color: green;}
</style>
<body>
  <ul class="product-list">
    <li><img src ="product1.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src ="product2.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src ="product4.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src ="product5.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src ="product3.jpg"/></li>
  </ul>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant, I added "src*=" instead of "src^=" but the rest of the code works as described (and was similar enough to mine to be easily readable). Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$(function() {
  /*Products we to target*/
  var products = ["product1.jpg", "product2.jpg", "product3.jpg"];
  for(i=0; i<products.length; i++) {
    $('ul.product-list li img[src*=]'+products[i]).addClass('targeted-product');
  }
});
```

Comment: That only handles the first one

Comment: So where is your loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a valid selector using the array, then use `.find()` to get the descendants.

```
var selector = products.map(function (p) {
    return "img[src*=" + p + "]"
}).join(',');

//Use the selector string
$('ul.product-list li').find(selector).addClass('targeted-product');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following:

Just need to add:

```
$('ul.product-list li 

    img[src*='+products['0']+']').addClass('targeted-product');

    $(function() {  
        /*Products we to target*/
        var products = ["product1.jpg", "product2.jpg", "product3.jpg"];
        $('ul.product-list li img[src*='+products['0']+']').addClass('targeted-product');
    });
```

Comment: this is invalid JS

Answer (score 0):

To add one more to the mix, using [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('ul.product-list li img').filter(function(){return products.indexOf($(this).attr('src')) !== -1;}).addClass('targeted-product');
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqge9anp/)